# What is the value of "a" if the area of triangle is 9.

Tags: geometry

> What is the value of "a" if the area of triangle is 9.

I know it looks easy but I find different answers for "a".I hope someone could help me.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have a function that looks like:

$$\text{y}\left(x\right)=\text{a}\cdot x+\text{b}\tag1$$

For the area we can write:

$$\mathcal{A}=\int_0^{x_1}\text{y}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\int_0^{x_1}\left(\text{a}\cdot x+\text{b}\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{x_1\cdot\left(\text{a}\cdot x_1+2\cdot\text{b}\right)}{2}=9\tag2$$

So, for $x_1$ you get:

$$x_1=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{18\cdot\text{a}+\text{b}^2}}{\text{a}}\tag3$$

Now, you can set up a system of equations using:

- When $x=0$:
  $$\text{y}\left(0\right)=\text{a}\cdot0+\text{b}=\text{b}\tag4$$
- When $x=x_1$:
  $$\text{y}\left(x_1\right)=\text{a}\cdot x_1+\text{b}=\text{a}\cdot\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{18\cdot\text{a}+\text{b}^2}}{\text{a}}+\text{b}=\pm\sqrt{18\cdot\text{a}+\text{b}^2}\tag5$$

Comment: If I have the numbers correctly, I think the line is annotated as $ax+2$.